# Perl Regular expression to replace the last matching string

Tags: regex, perl

I have a string as below:

```
$str = "/dir1/dir2/dir3/file.txt"
```

I want to remove the **/file.txt** from this string.

So that the **$str** will become.

```
$str = "/dir1/dir2/dir3"
```

I am using the following regex. But it is replacing everything.

```
$str =~ s/\/.*\.txt//;
```

How can I make regex to look for last **'/'** instead of first.

What is the correct regular expression for this?

Please note that **file.txt** is not fixed name. It can be anything like **file1.txt**, **file2.txt**, etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this regex

```
m/(.*)\/[^\/]*$/
```

the first submatch is the path you are looking for.

**EDIT:**

If you are looking for substitution user1215106's soultion is the way to go:

```
s/\/[^\/]*$//
```

Comment: You also forgot to escape the delimiter in the character class.

Comment: @Saumita - You have accepted this answer? How can this work for you? See http://ideone.com/GVagS - it gives you empty string. It should be `s/(.*)\/[^\/]*$/$1/` or `s/\/[^\/]*$//` as shown in my answer.

Comment: @user1215106 he have mentioned that the first submatch is the path..so i used $1 and it worked perfectly for me..see http://ideone.com/3tloG

Comment: @Saumita - Yes, `$1` match it, **but** he uses substitution `s/../../` which is for modification and not matching, so he wash out the input string - see here: http://ideone.com/K5qe2

Comment: @Saumitra user1215106 is correct in the sense that this solution is destructive. You would get the exact same result using his solution, without the need to destroy your original data. And of course `File::Basename` does not even change your variables.

Comment: @user1215106 & TLP: I am sorry I did not mean to cause any dispute. I am not familiar with pearl I normally use regex in php context. I was not aware that I did use substitution, I thouht it would be perl synthax. I changed my answer that i hopefully fits your expectaions. *I hope this settles any dispute.*

Comment: @flec - it is not about dispute, but about correct answer, so next users can read correct solution when they are looking for similar or same task. I am glad you edited you answer and made correction. Now it is okay. Thanks ang good luck!

Comment: @user1215106 flec's solution worked for me so I accepted it as answer...in future I will try to accept not only the correct answer but also the best one...anyway thanks to both of you..PEACE :)

Answer (score 6):

If you want to get the path from that string, you can use [File::Basename](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?File%3a%3aBasename). It is a core module since Perl version 5.

```
perl -MFile::Basename -le '$str = "/dir2/dir3/file.txt"; print dirname($str);'
```

In script form:

```
use strict;
use warnings; # always use these
use File::Basename;

my $str = "/dir1/dir2/dir3/file.txt"; 
print dirname($str);"
```

Your regex does not work because it is not anchored, and `.*` is greedy, so it matches as much as it can, starting from the first slash `/` it encounters. A working regex would look something like these:

```
$str =~ s#/[^/]*?\.txt$##;
```

Note the use of a non-greedy quantifier `*?`, which will match smallest possible string. Also note that I use another delimiter for the substitution to avoid the "leaning toothpick syndrome", e.g. `s/\/\/\///`.

Comment: thanks for introducing me to File::Basename and the nice explanation

Comment: @Saumitra You're welcome. You should not be afraid to use modules. This one will already be available on your system (unless your perl installation is going on 20 years old).

Comment: good code and good advise as usual. but sometimes i like to use `rindex($str,'/')`.

Comment: @loldop That's a pretty clean way to do it. I'd completely forgotten about that function.

Answer (score 3):

Very simple regex : `s/\/[^\/]*$//`

Comment: @Saumitra That is because he forgot that he must escape the delimiter `/`, even inside a character class.